# Visual Basic Error while Creating a new UIButtonControl

Tags: arcobjects

I am trying to add a new form that a programmer sent me for a specific UIButtonControl. When I import the form into Visual Basic following the steps they sent me, it imports the form as a module instead of a new form. when I try to use the new UIButtonControl button that I created with the module, it gives me this error: Compile Error. Invalid outside procedure. Both the programmer and myself feel it is because visual basic is bringing the form in as a module instead of a form, can anyone help me fix this please?

Comment: are you both developing in VBA? Or has the programmer created the form in VB6 and you are importing it into VBA?  In VBA, this should be a straight forward export - import (the form export generated 2 files .frm and .frx)

Answer (score 1):

If you are both using VBA you could have the programmer save the form and the code in the document. He could then send you the document complete with the UI button and the form so you could test it on your end.